# How to call ParsePush.SubscribeInBackground method only Once in android application?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse server in my android application. and also using parse push service.
I have set

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("ChannelName");
```

in my application class.

When user disables notification from app settings, I am using

```
ParsePush.unSubscribeInBackground("ChannelName");
```

but the problem is that, I called parse push subscribe method in my application class, so it again sets "ChannelName" in Installation table.

**Question** - 
Where do I declare `ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("ChannelName")` method in my android app?

I wants to call `ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("ChannelName")` only Once. when user first installs my Android app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks Everyone, Problem Resolved. I Referred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134718/android-how-to-call-method-only-on-installation-of-app link.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve a list of channels that have been subscribed too by checking the ParseInstallation. No need to persist additional data to SharedPreferences. Check the ParseInstallation to see if the channel has been subscribed to, if so then don't re-subscribe.

```
final ParseInstallation mInstall = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
final List<String> mList = mInstall.getList("channels");

//there are no subscriptions listed on the parse installation
if( mList == null )
{
    //subscribe
}

else if ( !mList.contains("KEY") )
{
    //subscribe
}
```

You could just use one if statement, but it could be hard to read and decipher later on if you are not careful.

```
if( mList != null && !mList.contains("KEY") ) 
{
    //subscribe!!!
}
```